# How can I set up a conditional breakpoint for the CreateFileW function for when a specific file/path is read in x64dbg?

Tags: debugging, x64dbg, breakpoint, winapi

I'm currently debugging a program using x64dbg, and I'm struggling to set up a conditional breakpoint on the [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) function:

```
HANDLE CreateFileW(
  [in]           LPCWSTR               lpFileName,
  [in]           DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess,
  [in]           DWORD                 dwShareMode,
  [in, optional] LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
  [in]           DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition,
  [in]           DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
  [in, optional] HANDLE                hTemplateFile
);
```

Specifically, I need the breakpoint to trigger *only* when the function is called with a specific filename/path, such as `"C:/my/file/txt.txt"`.

Despite searching online, I haven't found a clear solution for my scenario. Can anyone guide how to achieve this in x64dbg?

**What I tried**

I tried to set a conditional breakpoint with:

```
arg.get(0) == "C:/my/file/"
```

However, that doesn't work, it seemingly breaks on *every* file, no matter the path.

- How can I set a conditional breakpoint for when the debugger is accessing the path of `C:/my/file/bla.txt`?